# Post Processing data after performing a single SQL search

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I have to create a 3 tier drop down navigation menu and am using the following code to perform the database lookup:

```
$pcategorysql = "SELECT parentcat, subcat, product FROM tblItems WHERE status='active' ORDER BY parentcat, subcat";
$pcategorydo = mysqli_query($mysqli, $pcategorysql);
if (!$pcategorydo) {die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));}
```

I then use `$pcatdata = $pcategorydo->fetch_assoc()` to put the data into a workable array.

What I then want to do is get the distinct values of `$pcatdata['parentcat']` which will create a div for each distinct value and will become the first level menu within each distinct parentcat then create a div inside this parentcat div that has distinct values of `$pcatdata['subcat']` and within each subcat div create another set of div's that are the distinct values of `$pcatdata['product']` Could anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this.

Comment: This query would not get a series of products. Those should be in a separate table, referencing your category.

Comment: This is not a shopping cart site and the setup of the database is custom and outside of my control there is not a separate categories table.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the id for all the categories (parentcat, subcat and product), so with this you will be able to write a series of loops when parsing the array, and then for every change of it you would create a div in your html code.

Cheers,

gines

Comment: This is not a shopping cart site and the setup of the database is custom and outside of my control there is not a separate categories table and no id's for them.